# Issues with retrieving profile image from Google Admin SDK/Directory API

Tags: google-directory-api

I am trying to retrieve a user's profile picture in Python using either the [users.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get) method or the [users.photos.get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users.photos/get) method from the Google Directory API. I have set up my service account with the proper scope, and I get a 200 response when calling both endpoints, and can view actual data for every field, but when trying to access the profile image, I get a generic silhouette image. The methods I have used to try and access the profile images are:

- With the `users.get` method, I have tried making a `get` call on the `thumbnailPhotoUrl` field using `AuthorizedHttp` under `google.auth.transport.urllib3` from the Python google-auth package. The `AuthorizedHttp` object is created using the google service account credentials.
- With the `users.photos.get` method I have tried decoding the `photoData` field with web-safe base64.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely their photo is only linked to their Gmail account profile, which is inaccessible via the Admin API. You need to upload their photo directly through the admin.google.com GUI. Then your request will return that photo.